# lean() inside populate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am populating a user collection in *mongoose* and  want to set a flag if the user is signed up using social accounts. So I am selecting that fields in *populate*. But due to security concerns I don't want to pass it in response. So I converted it into plain object using `lean()` and set the values as `null`. But once a values are set `null` for a particular user then it set that values null for that `user_id`. How set them `null` or how to hide them from response.

```
 Pins.find(condition)
   .limit(limit)
   .sort({time: -1})
   .populate({
     path: 'user_id',
     select: '_id name pic twitter_id fb_id',
     options: { lean: true}
   })
   .lean()
   .exec(function(err, data) {

        if(data){
         var flag = 0
            async.eachSeries(data, function(v, callback1) {

              if(v.user_id.twitter_id || v.user_id.fb_id ){
                  v.socialaccount=1
                  v.user_id.fb_id =''
                   v.user_id.twitter_id =''
              }else{
                  v.socialaccount=0 
                      v.user_id.fb_id =''
                   v.user_id.twitter_id =''
              }
             callback1()



     },function(){
              console.log(data)
             callback(data)  

            })

        } else {
            callback(data)
        }

    })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By far i am understanding is that , you have a Pins collections which has a userid refering to User collection. And you want a response that the Pin made by user has a social account on twitter or facebook associated with your database or not. Am i right ?

Comment: yes. I just want to set a flag for that. But i don't want to pass fb_id or twitter_id  in my response

Comment: You can use **lodash**  for that... to remove 'user_id' from the resultant array of objects.

Comment: But if i remove user_id all populated user details will be removed but i need other details like name,pic

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here it is.

```
Pins.find(condition)
  .limit(limit)
  .sort({time: -1})
  .populate({
    path: 'user_id',
    select: '_id name pic twitter_id fb_id',
    options: { lean: true}
  })
  .lean().exec(function(err, pins) {
  if(pins){

    pins = _.map(pins,function(pin) {

      //Setting the flag for social account
      pin.socialaccount = (pin.user_id.twitter_id || pin.user_id.fb_id );

      //Omitting the twitter_id and fb_id fields from user_id object
      pin.user_id.twitter_id = undefined;
      pin.user_id.fb_id = undefined;
      return pin;
   });

   return res.send(pins);
 }

})
```

I have mapped the pins collection from the find query such that you can set your **socialaccount** flag and can set the properties not required to **undefined**

However i am not sure if you can use `_.omit(pin.user_id,'twitter_id')` instead of  `pin.user_id.twitter_id = undefined`.Need to test that !

The result pins collection will now have other user properties you wanted.
Hope it helps :)